# Is there any way to split quanteda tokens into n equal parts?

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I'm performing text analysis using the `quanteda` package in R.

I have a set of text documents that I already tokenized. Each consists of a different amount of tokens. I want to split the tokens into N equal chunks of tokens (e.g. 10 or 20 chunks that consist of an equal amount of tokens for each text).

Assume my data is called `text_docs` and looks as follows:

```
Text  | Tokens
Text1 | "this" "is" "an" "example" "this" "is" "an" "example"
Text2 | "this" "is" "an" "example"
Text3 | "this" "is" "an" "example" "this" "is" "an" "example" "this" "is" "an" "example"
```

The results that I would like to get should look like this (with two chunks instead of twenty):

```
Text  | Chunk1                                 | Chunk2
Text1 | "this" "is" "an" "example"             | "this" "is" "an" "example"
Text2 | "this" "is"                            | "an" "example"
Text3 | "this" "is" "an" "example" "this" "is" | "an" "example" "this" "is" "an" "example"
```

I'm aware of the `tokens_chunk` function in `quanteda`. Yet, this function only enables me to create a set of chunks of equal size (e.g. each chunk consists of two tokens), which leaves me with a different amount of chunks. Furthermore, the command `size` in the `tokens_chunk` function has to be a single integer, which is why I can't simply do this `chunks <- tokens_chunk(text_docs, size = ntokens(text_docs)/20)`.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What object class do you want as your output? What you show is not an R object, but rather a table. tokens objects do not have partitions, so do you want Text1.1, Text1.2, Text 2.1, etc or would some other base R object work for you?

Comment: I'm sorry for displaying a 'non-R' output. As this is my first post on stackoverflow I was not sure how to display the desired output. It would be great if the output were Text1.1, Text1.2 and so on as my next step would be to create a document-term matrix. However, I could also work with something like a data.frame as well, if this were easier to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

toks <- c(
  Text1 = "this is an example this is an example",
  Text2 = "this is an example",
  Text3 = "this is an example this is an example this is an example"
) %>%
  tokens()

toks
## Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
## Text1 :
## [1] "this"    "is"      "an"      "example" "this"    "is"      "an"     
## [8] "example"
## 
## Text2 :
## [1] "this"    "is"      "an"      "example"
## 
## Text3 :
##  [1] "this"    "is"      "an"      "example" "this"    "is"      "an"     
##  [8] "example" "this"    "is"      "an"      "example"
```

Here's one way to do what you want.  We will lapply over the docnames to slice out each document, and then split it using `tokens_chunk()` with a size equal to half of its length.  Here, I also use `ceiling` so that if the token length is odd for a document, it will have one more token in its first split than in its second.  (Your example was all for even-tokened documents, but this handles the odd-tokened case too.)

```r
lis <- lapply(
  docnames(toks),
  function(x) tokens_chunk(toks[x], size = ceiling(ntoken(toks[x]) / 2))
)
```

That results in a list of split tokens, and you can recombine them by using the `c()` function which concatenates tokens.  You apply this to the list using `do.call()`.

```r
do.call("c", lis)
## Tokens consisting of 6 documents.
## Text1.1 :
## [1] "this"    "is"      "an"      "example"
## 
## Text1.2 :
## [1] "this"    "is"      "an"      "example"
## 
## Text2.1 :
## [1] "this" "is"  
## 
## Text2.2 :
## [1] "an"      "example"
## 
## Text3.1 :
## [1] "this"    "is"      "an"      "example" "this"    "is"     
## 
## Text3.2 :
## [1] "an"      "example" "this"    "is"      "an"      "example"
```